# Git push failing for a file ~90mb ... under 100mb

Tags: git

I get the following on a simple git push command:

```
Enumerating objects: 22, done.
Counting objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Delta compression using up to 10 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 86.68 MiB | 34.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 13 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
error: RPC failed; HTTP 400 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 400
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

this isn't the first commit or push. The other pushes have worked. This one seems to fail assumingly cos of the file size. But that's defo under 100mb. There's no other changes part of this commit.

Comment: Offtopic: it is not recommended to track large files (resources) by git. Did you configured Large File Support (LFS) for git? https://git-lfs.com/

Comment: less than 100mb should be fine but yeah tbf I am getting the same error after using git lfs running ... as suggest on https://git-lfs.com/

Comment: Running `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` should help, though @MarekR is correct. You better use LFS, or don't commit such large files at all, and distribute them somehow else (e.g. a zip archive put into GitHub release). Otherwise it will be pain to clone your repository, and every version of this file will be stored

Comment: omg the trick is you have to add it with git lfs ... I had reset my branch pre-vid commit so it was back in staging. But I had to restore it and then do a git add for it to be picked up. 

so git add is the secret sauce

Comment: What's so special about 100MB? Is that a limit of the git service you are using? (What git service are you using? Please add that information to the question, because the answer may depend on the service.)

Comment: The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-postbuffer) is clear that you should not need to set `http.postbuffer` unless you have a very broken HTTP server or proxy and that in almost all cases it simply serves to waste lots of memory.